Natural deduction proof help please!
I've been wondering the question for a few days.
How to prove ∃x∀y(x = y) ⊢ ∀x∀y(x = y) ?
I would appreciate it for your answers.

The premise assumes there is a single witness element, say, a which equals every element including itself via ∃-elim rule, intuitively this singleness implies that any two elements in the domain are equal via transitivity of identity after formally assuming two arbitrary elements x and y with consecutive nested scope inside the first scope and then applying ∀-elim twice. Finally you consecutively introduce universality twice out of the above assumed scopes including that of a since by now your generalization result no longer depends on the said witness a...

Thanks for your advice! I need some time to comprehend it.

Prove by contradiction. Assume not all x and y are equal. That means there is at least one y for which x=y is false. But the premise was that x=y is true for all y.

The inference is not valid.
As Hypathia of Alexandria told her students, two things that are identical to a third thing are identical to each other.
Transitivity, as @ doubleknot said.
But your your premise posits the existence of only a single one of the x, the one that is identical  to all of the y. There could be a whole herd of x that are not y, but your conclusion makes an unwarranted  universal statement about all of them.

The inference is valid. We don't like to provide complete solutions to homework questions on this site, so the comment from DoubleKnot containing hints at a proof is a satisfactory response.

@Bumble Sorry, I didn't see an indicator that this was homework. (Is there one?) I completely stay away from homework help stuff. I only want to answer questions that the person is actually interested in. === The inference is valid. === If x is the animals in a  zoo in 'Frisco, and y is a herd of zebras in Africa, then one of the zoo animals (the zebra) is equal to each of the herd zebras, and none of the other zoo animals are. But the conclusion was universally instantiated over the set of x — the zoo animals.

Simple logic proof questions nearly always are homework unless they say otherwise. The inference is valid. You are not entitled to suppose that the variables x and y range over different domains. Both expressions are true if and only if the domain contains a single individual.

@MissUnderstands Sorry, my bad, actually it's homework. I just want to get some hint.

@MissUnderstands, that is not how such tasks work in logic exercises. Both x and y are assumed to be from the same set unless otherwise stated.  For you zoo example, the task would need to state otherwis that the domains of x and y are not same. In logic, if nothing else is said, the domains are same, e.g. both x and y must be from the herd of zebras.

@tkruse >  You are not entitled to suppose that the variables x and y range over different domains. === I almost added that caveat to my answer. Yes, of course, if the zoo contains only zebras, then yes, the inference is valid. But that was never specified in the problem, which is why I ignored it. People hate when I wander off into discussions of tangential issues, and that was one.
